# What does it mean to be a part of XYZ Battalion in World War 1?

Tags: military-records, world-war-1, canada

I found my great-grandfather's obituary and it says that he was a WW1 veteran and that he was a part of the 25th and 46th Battalion.

What does this mean?

[image: Unattributed newspaper cutting]

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: Are all the named survivors listed in this clipping deceased? If not, the image should be removed from the question and replaced by a transcription of the relevant portions. The deceased's sons and daughters aren't relevant to the question and shouldn't be exposed here.

Comment: Given that the cutting has already been published in the original papers, @JanMurphy surely it makes no difference to data protection to re-publish it? We run the risk of having a policy that people simply don't understand if we require the total exclusion of the names of living people. If it were a transcript I would (a) be worried about confusing Battery and Battalion and (b) ask what the Regiment was in the original (This way, I can see that there isn't one).

Comment: @AdrianB38 But our current policy does require the total exclusion of the names of living people... shall we go round the topic again on Meta? Also, for copyright purposes, the image should be attributed

Comment: I have done the redaction, but am also uncomfortable that the clipping isn't attributed and is probably still in copyright.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - thank you for the redaction, I don't have any problem with someone volunteering to do that. I'm not sure I see the necessity but... So that makes 3 issues with this question - copyright, terms & conditions (of use of the clipping) and "data protection". Can we raise this on Meta (since it is not a duplicate of "Allowing links to images of public documents containing living people")? Err, sorry not sure of the protocol: Who asks the meta question?

Comment: @AdrianB38 Anyone can ask the meta question -- might make sense to separate the issues around ts&cs/attribution from the data protection ones as they're two unrelated set of questions (and we've discussed data protection at lot, and wouldn't want that to swamp the other issue?)

Answer (score 2):

See the Wikipedia list article on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_infantry_battalions_in_the_Canadian_Expeditionary_Force